# Identify and add HTML class to masonry items by their position

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, addclass, masonry

I am using Masonry to render a group of items in two columns. Given below is the HTML structure.

```
<div id="grid">
 <article class="entry"> … </article>
 <article class="entry"> … </article>
 <article class="entry"> … </article>
 <!-- And so it goes -->
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is identify which one of the item is in the ‘Left Column’ and which one is in the ‘Right Column’ and add an HTML class based on that. The way I chose to identify the item placement is by their position attribute, e.g. for those items to the left it would equal to ‘0’ and likewise the following JS was coded.

```
var $grid = $('#grid');
$grid.imagesLoaded( function() {
    $grid.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.entry',
    percentPosition: true,
    columnWidth: 20,
    gutter: 25,
    isAnimated : false
  });
});
$("#grid .entry").each( function() {
    var position = $(this).position();
    if( position.left == 0) {
      $(this).addClass('left-column');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('right-column');
   }
});
```

The problem being faced is that, each one of the item is being identified as being located to the left. Can you please describe what are the glitches or suggest any alternative method? Your assistance would be highly appreciated.

I have created a JSfiddle, here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/DhrubaRC/7441frh3/

Thank you!

Comment: my suggest would be to not use "noname" frameworks and etc. in other words write native code and use standarts

Comment: When your code runs, it will run before masonry has finished.  Try running your function in a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Masonry (Desandro did a fantastic job with that and Isotope): http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/methods.html#layout the layout method accepts a 3rd argument, which is the callback argument.

You may want to count the number of matching 'entry' elements first, then call the Masonry function, and in the callback, check the index you're on is equal to 1 less than the number of elements (i.e. if you've done them all) and when it is, call the $('#grid .entry').each.... code.  By that point, all the positioning information should be set and work as you intended.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I think with [layoutComplete](http://masonry.desandro.com/events.html#layoutcomplete) the same could be achieved. How does it compare to your solution? Also, how would these perform with Infinite scroll? I have updated the jsfiddle. Thank you again!

Comment: Hi @Dhruba layoutComplete is sometimes buggy for me, but you may get better mileage.  I often had layoutComplete trigger before all items were in position.  Try it and see? but the method above seems to be very reliable (although a bit more brute-force).  With infinite scroll (or adding items on scroll, Masonry lets you poke new items in and you should be able to do a similar kind of callback on the newly added items.